# LoginRequiredMiddleware not working for Unauthenticated User

Tags: python, django

I am trying to automate the links access for authenticated and unauthenticated users using LoginRequiredMiddleware. The code is not working as unauthenticated users can still open other urls which they are not supposed to. Please see my code below and advise. Thanks.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
    LoginView, LogoutView, 
    PasswordResetView, PasswordResetDoneView,
    PasswordResetConfirmView,
    PasswordResetCompleteView
)

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.home, name = 'home'),
    path('column/', views.column),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), name = 'login'),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'), name = 'logout'),
    path('register/', views.register, name = 'register'),
    path('profile/', views.view_profile, name = 'view_profile'),
    path('profile/edit/', views.edit_profile, name = 'edit_profile'),
    path('change_password/', views.change_password, name = 'change_password'),
    path('reset-password/', PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='accounts/reset_password.html'), name = 'password_reset'),
    path('reset-password/done', PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name = 'password_reset_done'),
    path('reset-password/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name = 'password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset-password/complete/$', PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

LOGIN_URL = 'login'

LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = (
    'logout',
    'register',
)
```

**LoginRequiredMiddleware.py**

```
import re

from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout

EXEMPT_URLS = [settings.LOGIN_URL.lstrip('/')]
if hasattr(settings, 'LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS'):
    EXEMPT_URLS += [url for url in settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS]

class LoginRequiredMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        assert hasattr(request, 'user')

        if request.user.is_authenticated is False:
            if view_func.__name__ in EXEMPT_URLS is False:
                return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)

        else:
            return None
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using the decorator or the view mixin as explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users?

Comment: @Risadinha If the idea is to prevent all views but one from being accessed when not logged in, then I think Middleware makes sense.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to avoid putting decorators for each view in views.py. Also when the user is not authenticated, they should be able to open Login and Register pages. For everything else they should be redirected to the login page. If you are already logged in then they should be able to see all pages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this middleware to your `MIDDLEWARE` setting in `settings.py`?

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'myproject.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: Yes, I have this in the settings: MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'tutorial.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
]

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint or at least a print statement to `process_view` to make sure it's being loaded?

Comment: I added: def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
              assert hasattr(request, 'user')
              print(request)                 Still no change. Do I need to qualify my 'view_func.__name__' method more? Not sure if it is associating it with 'def process_view' properly...

Comment: When you say no change, are you seeing the print showing up in your console? I would be inclined to print something obnoxious like "\n\n***********Middleware fired**********\n\n"

Comment: This is showing in the console  [19/Feb/2020 17:32:29] "GET /account/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2821


***********Middleware fired**********


[19/Feb/2020 17:32:31] "GET /account/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3698


***********Middleware fired**********

Comment: OK, but you're on the login and register urls. Try another url?

Comment: Hi Greg,I have added a reverse() method before the url name 'login' in middleware. Also added 'home' url in LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS in settings.The 'register' url seems to be working now and I get the registration form. However when I submit form it takes to home page but does not log the user in automatically. If I try to access the login page 'account/login' it just goes in an endless loop. Both these seem to indicate issue with the url 'login'. I get the error: [20/Feb/2020 18:02:04] "GET /account/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0. Maybe a leading / issue? Would appreciate if you have any thoughts on this.